# SQL complex GROUP BY on either of two fields

Tags: mysql

Say I have a relation (table) like this:

```
 name | mother | father
------+--------+--------
  joe |    sue |    ted
 lisa |    sue |    ted
  ron |    sue |   john
 jose |  maria | javier
 ...  many more items
```

Assume the names are globally unique. How can I group (joe, lisa, ron)
as a set, based on the definition of a group as any rows that share
either a mother or a father?

SQL for either MySQL or PostgreSQL would be fine.

Comment: ok I guess my answer will not give the one you are looking at. Deleting it.

Comment: can you post what you would like to see the outcome to be?

Comment: if there were a third child nick, mother=maria father=john, would nick be in the same group as joe,lisa,ron ? (and would then jose be in the group also?)

Comment: @Andras Let's stipulate that that scenario (nick) will never happen. .

Comment: I expect better than this.

Comment: OK I will try to reformulate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot be done as described.

Let's draw a picture.  Here are 4 parents and 3 children:

```
M1  F1  M2  F2
 \  /\  /\  / 
  C1  C2  C3
```

Consider the group containing C1.  This group also contains C2, as a half-sibling.

Since the group contains all children who share a parent, this group must contain C3, because C2 and C3 share a parent.

But since this group contains only children who share at least one parent, this group cannot contain C3, because C1 and C3 do not share any parents.

C3 must be simultaneously both contained and not contained, by definition.  So it would appear that such a group is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

one thing you can do is use an exists condition to compare the mother or father and give it a limit to say that there is more than just one of the mother or father.

```
SELECT distinct name
FROM table p
WHERE EXISTS
(   SELECT 1
    FROM table p1
    WHERE p1.mother = p.mother
    LIMIT 1, 1
)
OR exists
(   SELECT 1
    FROM table p2
    WHERE p2.father = p.father
    LIMIT 1, 1
)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76b0d/1)**

### EDIT:

a way you can spearate each group apart is with something like this

```
SELECT name, mother_father_group
FROM
(   SELECT distinct 
        name, mother, father,
        @groups := IF(@mother = mother OR @father = father, @groups, @groups + 1) as mother_father_group,
        @mother := mother, @father := father
    FROM upeople p, (SELECT @mother := "", @father := "", @groups := 0) temp
    WHERE EXISTS
    (   SELECT  1
        FROM    upeople p1
        WHERE   p1.mother = p.mother
        LIMIT 1, 1
    )
    OR exists
    (   SELECT 1
        FROM    upeople p2
        WHERE   p2.father = p.father
        LIMIT 1, 1
    )
)t
```

[**ANOTHER DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a7fe/1)

Comment: won't that just give you the list of names who have siblings?  that doesn't group them (cute trick, using limit 1,1 to skip self btw)

Comment: @Andras yep... like i asked in my comment the OP needs to clarify what he wants to be returned... does he want to specify a specific mother or father? does he want to just want to list them all out? what does the OP want to show for multiple groups? 'ron' has a different mother father combo, so why is ron in this group?

Comment: the group is those kids who share _either_ a mother _or_ a father.  Ron has the same mother, so he's in.  (I.e., this is a group of siblings and half-siblings.)  What I don't know is if the group should transitively include half-siblings of half-siblings who are not biologically related to all other group members (my nick example in my question to the OP)

Comment: @Andras i understand that part but what i'm asking is does the OP want separate columns for the different groups? or what about some indicator column? or does he want to specify a particular mother or father? its not clear

Comment: @Andras i added multi group functionality only thing it doesn't account for is a mother or father across multiple groups